# Tried to make a program that reconstructs numbers in string from a jumble string but got index out of bound error

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

423. Reconstruct Original Digits from English

> Given a string s containing an out-of-order English representation of
> digits 0-9, return the digits in ascending order.

I tried the code in Java but it somehow is throwing an error for Index out of Bound

It works for other inputs but throws the error for this input

```
public static String originalDigits(String s){
    StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder(s);
    StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder();

    while(st.length()!=0){
    if (st.indexOf("z")!=-1){
        num.append("0");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("z"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
    }

    if (st.indexOf("o")!=-1 && st.indexOf("n")!=-1){
        num.append("1");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("w")!=-1){
        num.append("2");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("w"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("h")!=-1 && st.indexOf("r")!=-1){
        num.append("3");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("h"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("u")!=-1){
        num.append("4");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("f"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("u"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("f")!=-1){
        num.append("5");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("f"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("v"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("x")!=-1){
        num.append("6");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("s"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("x"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("v")!=-1){
        num.append("7");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("s"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("v"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("g")!=-1){
        num.append("8");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("g"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("h"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
        
    }

    if (st.indexOf("n")!=-1){
        num.append("9");
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
        st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
        
    }
    System.out.println(num);
  }
    
    String num1 = new String(num);
    return num1;
}
```

The error specifically is : [Error Showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hTMJ.png)

[Question Link](https://leetcode.com/problems/reconstruct-original-digits-from-english/)

Comment: The way you are checking to see what number is contained in the string means you are probably catching the wrong number by mistake. Because of this, your calls to `deleteCharAt()` are sometimes being given -1 as the index, because the matching call to `indexOf()` is NOT finding what you are expecting. Rather than check for one or two letters in the string... why not check the whole string?

Comment: What if the given string is "fournine", your check for digit 1 will fail the process.

Comment: I thought it would be much more efficient if I check only some unique to the name letters rather than the whole thing

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the order of the checks for certain letters. Start with the digits whose names contain a unique letter, i.e.

- z for 0
- w for 2
- u for 4
- x for 6
- g for 8

Of-course continue to remove the relevant letters – as you are already doing.

After that, check for the letter *f* since you have removed all the letters *f*, *o*, *u* and *r* (for the digit 4) and therefore any remaining letter *f* will indicate that the string contains the letters for the digit 5.

After that, check for the letter *v* (for the digit 7)

Then check for the letter *h* (for the digit 3)

Then check for *i* (9)

Finally check for *n* (1).

This will fix your `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` but you may fail due to *time limit exceeded*.

Note that many, if not all, *leetcode* problems have online solutions. For problem 423, I found [this answer](https://walkccc.me/LeetCode/problems/0423/#__tabbed_1_2).

Here is your code with my corrections – as described above. When I submitted this solution, I got *time limit exceeded*.

```java
class Solution {
    public String originalDigits(String s) {
        StringBuilder st = new StringBuilder(s);
        StringBuilder num = new StringBuilder();
        while(st.length() != 0) {
            if (st.indexOf("z") != -1) {
                num.append("0");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("z"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("w") != -1) {
                num.append("2");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("w"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("u") != -1) {
                num.append("4");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("f"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("u"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("x") != -1) {
                num.append("6");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("s"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("x"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("g") != -1) {
                num.append("8");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("g"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("h"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("h") != -1) {
                num.append("3");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("t"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("h"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("r"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("f") != -1) {
                num.append("5");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("f"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("v"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("v") != -1) {
                num.append("7");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("s"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("v"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("i") != -1) {
                num.append("9");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("i"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
            }
            else if (st.indexOf("o") != -1) {
                num.append("1");
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("o"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("n"));
                st.deleteCharAt(st.indexOf("e"));
            }
        }
        char[] digits = num.toString().toCharArray();
        java.util.Arrays.sort(digits);
        return new String(digits);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You but yes indeed it is showing the error.

Comment: @AryanKaushik that means you need to think of a better algorithm. Did you look at the solution I linked to in my answer?